# How to start pandas categorical column encoding from a specific number?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I have a categorical column in a pandas data frame like the following.

```
State
=====
New York
California
Utah
Arizona
................
```

I have encoded the column-like following.

```
df.state = pd.Categorical(df.state)
df.state = df.state.astype('category').cat.codes
```

I print the column

```
print(df['state'].unique())
```

I am getting

```
[-1, 0, 1, 2]
```

Instead of starting from -1, how can I start codes from 0? Also, after encoding, how to know the labels of the code?

Comment: just add 1 to the codes?

Comment: `pd.Categorial(df['state'])` does that work?

Comment: This should work.  df['state'].astype('category').cat.codes

Comment: Above solutions work for some columns. However, for others they are not working.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. There must be an issue